# can anyone please let me know what does this line do in my python CODE:

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, iterator

ok so here is the code and i need to know what does this code do when below condition do not match and is there any simpler way to do that ,so i can understand it.

```
major = []
current_major = []
specs={'row': 2, 'exchange': 'NSE', 'name': 'WIPRO', 'token': 969473}
received_token = [969473,415745,12145]

        if specs['token'] not in received_token:
            values = major[[x[0] for x in major].index(name[:-3])]
            current_major.append(values)

            major = current_major
            current_major = []
            #sht2.range('A2').value = major  # using xlwings for live data to excel
            major.append(values)
```

Comment: You are doing `if not in` check which in this case is not true and you have no else, that means both `major` and `current_major` will be empty. Please provide a complete code.

Comment: hi ssharma, actually i just need to know what does " values = major[[x[0] for x in major].index(name[:-3])] " code does in my code

Comment: Are you sure this code runs without error?  I get the 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list' error for the line you said

Comment: @K47 yes the code runs .. i just need to know what does the line values = major[[x[0] for x in major].index(name[:-3])] does

Comment: The line consists of a list comprehension `[x[0] for x in major]`, which returns a list consisting of the first item of `x[0]` for all elements `x` in `major`. For this list, the method `index(val)` is called, which returns the index `idx` of the first list element whose value is equal to `val`. In your code, `val` is derived from `name` by omitting the last 3 elements (or characters, if `name` is a string). Finally, the resulting `idx` is used to look up the value in `major`.

Comment: Overall, I consider this question incomplete, and with relatively little value for other SO users. Could you maybe reformulate this question to make it more general? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your reply in comments, here is what `values = major[[x[0] for x in major].index(name[:-3])]` is doing.

```
# Case 1
major = [['WI',
        'WR','WW','WK','WI','WL']]
specs={'row': 2, 'exchange': 'NSE', 'name': 'WIPRO', 'token': 969473}
name = specs['name']

values = major[[x[0] for x in major].index(name[:-3])]
print(values)

# Case 2
major = [['WP',
        'WR','WW','WK','WI','WL']]

values = major[[x[0] for x in major].index(name[:-3])]
print(values)
```

In case 1: You have `name[:-3]` which is `WI` in `major` list hence you get the list `major` back at that `0` index as output. (`.index()` function look for the index of the element in major)

Output:

```
['WI', 'WR', 'WW', 'WK', 'WI', 'WL']
```

In case 2: `WI` is not present in the `major` hence you get an error:

```
ValueError: 'WI' is not in list
```